# SQL - concatenated string in where clause not working as expected - Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

This is the SQL (Redshift) I am referring to:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table_a
 WHERE col_a||col_b NOT IN 
            (
                SELECT col_a||col_b 
                  from table_b
            );
```

There are values in table_a which don't exist in table_b, yet this always evaluates to a No rows.

Any insight?

Comment: Provide your expected output and if possible then table schema as well.

Comment: Schema:
CREATE TABLE table_a (col_a varchar(40), col_b varchar(255));
CREATE TABLE table_b (col_a varchar(54), col_b varchar(255));

Comment: This is because of NOT IN . If your sub query Select col_a||col_b from table_b contains any null values then it will not give any output. Make sure ou apply filter of NOT NULL in subquery to get proper output.

Comment: Actually, the subquery does have a not null: SELECT * 
  FROM table_a
 WHERE col_a||col_b NOT IN 
            (
                SELECT col_a||col_b 
                  from table_b WHERE col_b IS NOT NULL
            );

Comment: can you try something like  SELECT col_a||col_b from table_b WHERE col_a IS NOT NULL AND col_b IS NOT NULL

Comment: That helps! Thank you!

Comment: IF any one field col_a or Col_b is null then entire value of col_a || col_b will become NULL. so you need to handle NULL values to default if possible or just exclude the records which has any one  or both column with null.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS`, not `NOT IN`!!!  `NOT IN` will return no rows at all if *any* value in the subquery is `NULL`.  Plus, you are comparing multiple columns by concatenating them.  That is likely to be a bad method because of collisions:  ab/c matches a/bc.

So use this:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table_a a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table_b b
                  WHERE b.col_a = a.col_a AND b.col_b = a.col_b
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The sub query might be having a null value, which is failing the not in clause.

Use coalesce to replace null with an appropriate value based on your data. I have used a ~ character in place of null

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table_a
 WHERE col_a||col_b NOT IN 
            (
                SELECT coalesce (col_a,'~')||coalesce (col_b , '~')
                  from table_b
            );
```